# Use NSDictionary 'initWithContentsOfURL' instead Reachability.h

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary, initwithcontentsofurl

I would like to better understand the functioning of of `initWithContentsOfURL` of `NSDictionary`.
This function manages by itself the failure of a connection?
From the `initWithContentsOfURL`  of `NSDictionary` reference:

> `- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL`
>
> > **Return Value**
> >
> > > An initialized dictionary-which Might be different than
> > >       the original-that contains the receiver at aURL dictionary, or nil if
> > >       there is an error or if the contents of the resource are an invalid
> > >       representation of a dictionary.

Ok, but does not specify whether the url passed is valid or not.

But since i'm sure my `plist` is well-formatted, i could use the method in question to see if the connection is available or not, instead of using the `Reachability.h`. It is of course just to understand if a data connection is available, not to understand what kind of connection is active(e.g. WiFi, etc).
I say this because if i do a simple test like this in airplane mode, `[dict count];` always returns 0.

```
NSURL * plist = [NSURL URLWithString: @ "http://www.example.com/example.plist"];
NSDictionary * dict = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:plist] autorelease];
  if ([dict count] == 0) {
      //no connection
  }
```

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Keep in mind that `[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:plist]` is a synchronous blocking call. If you block the main thread too long then you'll get 0x8BADF00D, and the watch dog will kill your process.

Comment: you mean if the plist has a large size?, because i see no other reasons that could block the main thread for a long time. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: If the network connect is slow for some reason, DNS resolution, any network problems that cause your request to be slooowww.

Comment: ..of course, and when you said "kill your process" you mean that the function returns nil or that the app crash?!

Comment: If you main thread blocks for too long (~10 seconds) then the system will kill your app, so yes it will crash.

Comment: now it's more clear. If no one offers a better answer, i consider it as accepted..thanks.